# Why do iron objects leave black marks on laminate countertop

Tags: everyday-chemistry, halogens

My over 30 years old laminate kitchen countertop had accumulated a lot of marks over the years that no cleaner would remove.  I finally gave up and decided to use chlorine bleach on it knowing that the bleach may damage it.  The bleach removed all the marks — looked like new.

There is only one unfortunate side effect: iron objects, e.g. cast iron, that come into contact with the countertop leave permanent black marks even a year after bleaching.  I suspect that the bleach damaged the seal on the countertop since I doubt any chemical residue from the bleaching would remain after a year.  On the other hand how could an over 30 year laminate countertop still have any kind of seal?

Any idea how I can prevent the black marks from iron objects?

Cheers and thanks.
[image]

Comment: There are a number of choices: a) accept it as patina, b) put a cloth over the countertop, c) rebleach after six months, d) try some wax, furniture polish, laquer, younameit to reseal the surface. There is no chemical, scientific answer to your question, how should anybody know what exactly your countertop surface is, now?

Comment: A photo might help, though.

Comment: I added a photo.

Comment: Never use a bleach on rust stains. Bleach can't remove rust it can only cause it become permanent. It will cause more problems. Rust stain will not dissolve by any typical home cleaner. There are commercial rust stain removers and they work like magic and in 5 minutes. Many of them should be available in a good grocery stores. The rust stain removers are either strong reducing agents or complexing agents and sometimes oxalic acid. Check with the manufacturer for safety as well.

Comment: Using a commonly available product that removes lime, calcium and rust, I was able to remove the stains.  Note that the manufacturer warns: "Vinyl or any other form of plastic can be easily damaged by the ingredient within the formulation." There was no damage to my countertop by the cleaner.